# Can't delete image which is being used by anoher process

Tags: java, image, exception

i started to use [thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) library to make thumbnail in a Spring Boot project 
But i'm facing a problem when i try to delete the file, i got an exception telling me the file is being used by another process. I pretty new with Java and i can't figured out where does the problem might come from and what process should i stop/close:

```
File originalFile = mediaUtils.saveFile(pathOriginal, file);

String path = mediaUtils.resolvePath(imageDir, name, false, image.getCreation());
mediaUtils.saveJPG(originalFile, file.getContentType(), WIDTH_IMAGE_SIZE, path);

String pathThumb = mediaUtils.resolvePath(imageDir, name, true, image.getCreation());
mediaUtils.saveJPG(originalFile, file.getContentType(), WIDTH_IMAGE_SIZE_THUMB, pathThumb);

public File saveFile(String filePath, MultipartFile file) {
try {
  Path path = Paths.get(getPath(filePath));
  Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());

  Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path);

  return new File(path.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {
  LOG.error("could not save file", e);
  throw new FileException("could not create file: " + getPath(filePath), e);
}
}

private void saveJPG(InputStream imageInputStream, File file, String contentType, int newWidth, String outputPath) {
try {
  // verify it is an image
  if (!Arrays.asList("image/png", "image/jpeg").contains(contentType)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file provided is not a valid image or is not supported (should be png or jpeg): " + contentType);
  }

  // Create input image
  BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);
  newWidth = newWidth > inputImage.getWidth() ? inputImage.getWidth() : newWidth;
  double ratio = (double) inputImage.getWidth() / (double) inputImage.getHeight();
  int  scaledHeight = (int) (newWidth / ratio);

  Path path = Paths.get(baseUrl + outputPath + ".jpg");

  Thumbnails.of(file)
    .size(newWidth, scaledHeight)
    .toFile(path.toFile());

  LOG.info("writing image to {}", path);

} catch (IOException e) {
  LOG.error("could not write image", e);
}
}
```

Thanks for any advice or help :)

Comment: oh ok you are not really interested in java you just want to use your thumblalnatr

Comment: I am but i'm in a specific situation, i am learning while working on a project so it's a bit difficult sometimes for me even with very basic thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure to close your inputstreams and files, after you've used them.
Otherwise things like you've mentioned, happen. A process does block your file.

So instead of using simple try-catch-blocks I would recommend to use try-with-resources which will close the underlying streams and files. For example:

```
try(InputStream imageInputStream = new FileInputStream(...)) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

After the code in the brackets is done or an exception occured, the inputstream will be closed.